# Path and string chopping in Powershell

Tags: regex, string, powershell, path, case-sensitive

I'm doing some work involving some automated file moving, and these files contain relative paths that must be maintained. Unfortunately, I'm finding the facilities offered by System.IO.Path, System.String, and Powershell's operators to be a little ill-equipped to handle my work gracefully.

One function that would be very useful to me is the notion of a subtraction of paths, that would work in theory like subtracting vectors. Conceptually, A - B gets you a path from B to A. In the application to paths, `D:\A\B\C\D - D:\A\B\ = \C\D`. Likewise, `D:\A\B\ - D:\A\B\C\D = \..\..` in this case. I can accept, for now, that this only makes sense when one path is wholly contained in the other.

This seems to consist of two steps: 1) determine containment of one path in the other. 2) remove the contained path from the containing path. 3) Optionally, replace folder names with the parent .. symbol based on the sidedness of the operation.

As I am concerned with NTFS, I need both containment and replacement operations to be case-insensitive. For containment, I can use select-string since it is case-insensitive, and allows the -simple switch which allows me to use a path without hacking it apart to escape them for regex.

Removing the string from the other is a little more annoying though. System.IO.Path has nothing for this, System.String's pertinent methods are all case-sensitive, and powershell's operators all require massaging so that the regex will match things.

All this seems like more work than it should be--are there any tools I'm missing that would better handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Determine containment - convert your paths to absolute paths (if not already).  You can use Resolve-Path for this. Then you can use $path1.StartsWith($path2, 'OrdinalIgnoreCase') to test for containment.
2. Remove contained path - $path1.Substring($path2.length)
3. Replace parent folder names with ... - although I don't have the regex off the top of my head, I'm pretty sure you could do this with a regular expression search/replace using PowerShell's -replace operator

Comment: I ended up using Substring for the subtraction on my own, after writing this, but to my surprise I had hidden the Resolve-Path cmdlet with a function of my own that was just checking Path.IsPathRooted and conditionally calling Path.Combine. Good to know there's one already there!

Comment: After some investigation into this Resolve-Path, it seems to have a -relative switch that's almost exactly what I was trying to implement, except that it seems to take one unnecessary step up and back dow. E.g. if you're in directory Main\ then Resolve-Path . -relative results in ..\Main for some reason. Very weird, but probably innocuous. Resolve-Path \ -relative performs correctly and doesn't try to step off the edge of the world.

Comment: Upon further usage, Resolve-Path has an exceedingly annoying obsession with verifying that the path it resolves actually exists; I see this as a violation of SRP since we already have Test-Path to do just that. At least make the path verification not on by default, and if not even that, then please at least a switch! All I want is a function that when given D:\folder and ..\file.txt, returns D:\file.txt regardless of whether or not it's there.

Comment: Well, in diselief that this function didn't exist, I poured over the functions on System.IO.Path again, and apparently the function I was hoping for out of Resolve-Path exists in System.IO.Path.GetFullPath. Not at all what I could expect a function with that name to do.

Answer (score 2):

[filedirectorypath](http://filedirectorypath.codeplex.com/), on CodePlex, may offer what you need

It's not a PowerShell specific API, but that's no reason not to use it from PowerShell.

### Benefits of the NDepend.Helpers.FilePathDirectory over the .NET Framework class System.IO.Path include:

- Strongly typed File/Directory path.
- **Relative / absolute path conversion.**
- Path normalization API
- Path validity check API
- Path comparison API
- Path browsing API.
- **Path rebasing API**
- List of path operations (TryGetCommonRootDirectory, GetListOfUniqueDirsAndUniqueFileNames, list equality…)